# How to get a percentage in a given decimal value

Tags: c#, percentage

I have a variable named `amountDue` which holds a Total amount of a transaction, another variable named `discount` which holds a discount in percentage which will be subtracted from `amountDue` and the result stored in another variable called `discountedAmount`.

My question is how can I calculate the discount given in percentage and subtract it from amount due and assign the new value to the Discounted Amount variable?

Comment: Why not give it a try. We are not here to do your homework. Seems simple math to me.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, What you have tried.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming, but simple math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might solve your problem

```
discountedAmount = amountDue * discount / 100;
```

For eg.

```
amountDue = Rs. 700
discount = 10%
discountedAmount = Rs. 70

Amount to be paid = Rs. 700 - 70 = Rs. 630
```

Comment: With such a simple question, at least explain what you are doing...

Comment: This is a basic aptitude question...

Comment: Then it should be simple to explain

Answer (score 0):

```
discountedAmount = amountDue - ((discount/100) * amountDue)
```

This is pretty basic math really. First of all, it's usually best to store percentages as a value between 0 and 1 instead of 0 and 100 (easier to calculate with).

First we divide the discount percentage by 100 to get that value between 0 and 1. Then we multiply this number by the total amount to get the currency value of the discount. Finally we subtract this value from the normal price to end up at the discounted price.

So, for something normally priced at 200$ with a discount of 10%, we get:

```
10 / 100 = 0.1
0.1 * 200 = 20 (the discount in dollars)
200 - 20 = 180 (the discounted price)
```

Comment: With such a simple question, at least explain what you are doing...